# "Only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars"

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, math

I have this code:

```
R = float(input("Enter the arc's radius of curvature: "))
H = float(input("Enter the arc's height: "))

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math

#cc = center of curvature
cc = math.sqrt(R**2 - (H / 2)**2)
x = np.linspace(-5,5,100)
y = math.sqrt(R**2 - (x - cc)**2)
plt.plot(x, y, 'c')
plt.show()
```

and get this error:

> TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

How can I fix this?

Comment: Why?  A python scalar is just one number.  An array with 2 numbers can be converted into just one, can it?  But which line is producing the error?  `math.sqrt` only works with one number.  But `x` is an array, so `R**2-(x-h)**2` is also an array.  That's my guess as to the problem line.  READ the `math` docs.  Test values in the problem line!  Do some of your own debugging.

Comment: It's the y = line.

Comment: @hpaulj: I get the same error when using polyfit(X,Y,Z,2) , to get a second degree polynomial to regress . Maybe problem is specifying which is the dependent variable?

Answer (score 4):

You can compute `y = math.sqrt(R**2 - (x - cc)**2)` as long as *x*
in a **single** variable, but in your code you attempt to compute
this expression for **each element** of *x* **array** (and get an array
of results).

To to this, proceed as follows:

1. Define your expression as a function:

   ```
    def myFun(R, x, cc):
        return math.sqrt(R**2 - (x - cc)**2)
   ```
2. Define **vectorized** version of this function:

   ```
    myFn = np.vectorize(myFun, excluded=['R', 'cc'])
   ```
3. Compute *y* as:

   ```
    y = myFn(R, x, cc)
   ```

For `R = 20.0`, `H = 30.0` and `x = np.linspace(-5,5,10)` (a shorter array)
I got:

```
array([ 8.22875656, 10.34341406, 11.99128261, 13.34639903, 14.49112624,
       15.47223243, 16.31925481, 17.05218586, 17.6852162 , 18.22875656])
```

Comment: Why not just use `np.sqrt(R**2 - (x-cc)**2)`?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem/error, what helped me was the answers by Stef and Nils Werner here:
[Solving only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69756374/solving-only-size-1-arrays-can-be-converted-to-python-scalars-error)

Basically, you cannot mix `.numpy` with `.math` functions because they expect different input types (arrays or single integers for numpy functions, but only single integers for math functions).

Answer (score 0):

See the solution below:

```
import numpy as ny
import matplotlib.pyplot as matplot

xcord = ny.arange(1, 5, 2.5)
ycord = ny.vectorize(ny.int)
matplot.plot(xcord, ycord(xcord))
matplot.show()
```

To see the full code explanation check [here](https://itsourcecode.com/python-tutorial/only-size-1-arrays-can-be-converted-to-python-scalars/).

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to create my first 3D plot using sample code I found on the web,

```
x = np.linspace(3700, 4000, 61)
y = np.linspace(10, 18, 9)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
Z = z_function(X, Y)
```

but my z_function produced the dreaded "TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars"

Rather than try to vectorize, I simply used for loops to create Z data:

```
Z = np.ones_like(X)
for i in range(len(X)):
    for j in range(len(X[0])):
        Z[i][j] = z_function(X[i][j],Y[i][j])
```

No error, worked easily and perfectly