# Unable to create chi squared expression for a contour plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, statistics

**The comment left by JohanC contains the solution to my problem, and as such there is no need to answer this question unless you want to add anything; otherwise, please do not use up your time with a triviality such as this.  Thanks all.**

I am in the early stages of learning python by forcing usage, and at the moment I am trying to generate a contour plot of a chi squared expression in matplotlib.  The requisite x,y data ('bladespace' and 'voltage') comes from two CSV files which I have successfully imported, while the free parameters are labeled 'w', and 'b'.  So far, I cannot successfully create a functional expression without throwing an error code.  So far, with math.erf I receive the following expression (with staggered lines to more easily find the line yielding the error):

```
    [map(
        sub, voltage, 1.4375 * math.erf((np.sqrt(2) / w) *
                                        [i - b for i in bladespace]) + 1.45195) ** 2])
```

which gives the error "TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars" on the line containing the variable w.  I tried using the vectorize function as expressed at this page:

["Only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63515866/only-size-1-arrays-can-be-converted-to-python-scalars)

to no avail.  Using scipy.special.erf, I get the expression:

```
    [map(
        sub, voltage, 1.4375 * sp.erf((np.sqrt(2) / w) *
                                        [i - b for i in bladespace]) + 1.45195) ** 2])
```

(nearly identical code, to be sure) along with the new error "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'map' and 'int'" from the line containing only `[map(`.

I'm sure it is clear that I am quite new to python, however I must find a solution one way or another.  Is there a simple fix which will allow me to generate a contour plot using this chi squared expression with x axis 'b' and y axis 'w'?  Should I be approaching this from a drastically different angle instead?

Thanks for any help or suggestions.

E: Upon reflection, I have decided it may be opportune to include the entirety of the code thus far:

```
from operator import sub
import numpy as np
import math
import pandas as pd
from scipy import special as sp

noerror = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\nickc\Desktop\School\20 - 21\4810\profile_data_without_errors_activity_2.csv")
werror = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\nickc\Desktop\School\20 - 21\4810\profile_data_with_errors_activity_2.csv")
bladespace = noerror["x"]
voltage = noerror["y"]
w = np.arange(.0105, .011, .001)
b = np.arange(.00005, .0004, .0005)

chi2 = sum(
    [map(
        sub, voltage, 1.4375 * math.erf((np.sqrt(2) / w) *
                                        [i - b for i in bladespace]) + 1.45195) ** 2])
```

Comment: Have you seen the scipy library? [Chi squared info is here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chi2.html).

Comment: You seem to be mixing a lot of concepts that don't mix well.  `map(function, iterable)` is a pure Python construct that needs as first parameter a function, and as second for example a list. You have 3 parameters.  `math.erf` is a function from the `math` library, which only acts on single numbers, not on lists. You are multiplying a python list with a floating point number; this is not supported.  You need a numpy array to multiply an array element-by-element with a float. The recommended approach would be to write everything with numpy, without `map` and without the `math` library.

Comment: @JohanC See I would've continued to miss that entirely.  So then I just need to convert the non-array objects into arrays, and it sounds like this whole thing will fall into place more smoothly, correct?

Comment: Once you get accustomed to numpy, it'll feel naturally. But it can take a while to grasp it.