# Solving only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars error

Tags: python, function, numpy, math

I have the following function however I have the error only "size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars" when I run the program

```
import math as math
import numpy as np

def chebs(c, d, n):
    k = np.array(range(n))
    y = ((2*k +1)*np.pi)/(4*(n+1))
    return c*math.sin(y)**2 + d*math.cos(y)**2
```

is there a way to circumvent the error? I'm assuming it comes from my use of math in the function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't mix `numpy.` with `math.` functions, just use `numpy.` functions only:

```
import numpy as np

def chebs(c, d, n):
    k = np.arange(n)
    y = ((2 * k + 1) * np.pi) / (4 * (n + 1))
    return c * np.sin(y) ** 2 + d * np.cos(y) ** 2
```

Answer (score 2):

The functions in `math` are usually expecting a single number as argument; whereas the functions in `numpy` are usually expecting anything from a single number to a multidimensional array, and will apply the mathematical function to every element in the array.

For instance:

```py
>>> import math
>>> import numpy as np

>>> math.sqrt(4)
2.0
>>> math.sqrt(25)
5.0
>>> np.sqrt(4)
2.0
>>> np.sqrt(25)
5.0

>>> np.sqrt([4,25])
array([2., 5.])

>>> math.sqrt([4,25])
TypeError: must be real number, not list

>>> math.sqrt(np.array([4,25]))
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

As it turns out, numpy arrays that contain a single number are able to implicitly convert themselves to a single number without array, when needed, so this works:

```py
>>> math.sqrt(np.array([[25]]))
5.0
```

The error message you got was telling you "the array `y` contains more than one number, so it can't be converted to a single number, so you can't call `math.sin` on it."

If you want to apply a function from `math` to every element in a list, you can do it using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) or using [builtin function `map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map). However, note that the whole point of `numpy` is to perform computations very fast on large arrays, and using list comprehensions or `map` will defeat that purpose.

```py
>>> list(map(math.sqrt, [4, 25]))
[2.0, 5.0]
>>> [math.sqrt(x) for x in [4,25]]
[2.0, 5.0]
```